# NpgSQL 4.1.3.1 I can connect to PostgreSQL 12 but not PostgreSQL11

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql

I can use C# and NpgSQL to connect to a PostgreSQL 12 instance. However when I use the same exact code to connect to a PostgreSQL 11 instance I get an exception. Object reference not set to an instance of an object. This is from line 1708 of NpgsqlConnector.cs (from disassembly).

The packages in my solution are as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces" version="1.1.1" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Npgsql" version="4.1.3.1" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="System.Buffers" version="4.5.0" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="System.Memory" version="4.5.3" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="System.Numerics.Vectors" version="4.5.0" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe" version="4.7.1" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="System.Text.Encodings.Web" version="4.6.0" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="System.Text.Json" version="4.6.0" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions" version="4.5.4" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="System.ValueTuple" version="4.5.0" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Teradata.Client.Provider" version="16.20.9" targetFramework="net471" />
</packages>
```

Comment: i would reach out to the npgsql project on github

Comment: They suggested stackoverflow with the npgsql tag :)

Comment: It sounds like a bug

Comment: Update after downloading the source the inner exception for PostgreSQL 11 is Error reading from stream in the DoReadMessage() method.

Comment: Can you share a [mcve], or if not, the full `ToString()` output of the exception including the exception type, message, traceback and inner exception(s) if any?  With just the information *`NullReferenceException` on line 1708 of NpgsqlConnector.cs* it's quite unlikely somebody will know how to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it was mostly my lack of experience with PostgreSQL.
I was lacking a pg_hba.conf entry for the machine I was trying to connect from. The error message was NOT very helpful...